# How do I create a specific URL Route

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have a web shop. I have some controllers and views to match /Admin/Index, /Admin/ShowProducts etc. all the stuff.

I want to be able to make a "custom" url that is always the same, and it should be in the root of my domain, like this:

www.mydomain.com/shop/myproduct

Where the shop is static and does not change, and the "myproduct" changes according toeach product (it is effectively an ID). How do I do this without getting the controller method displayed within the URL which is the default way?

Is this a new Route? or can I do something on a controller?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The default MVC route almost does it already.

Look at the Controller = and Action =

So make a URL like:

/shop/{id}

Controller = ShoppingController, Action = Shop

Note I added an assumption that the user doesn't have to specify the product, and you get some string to tell you it's the defaultproduct, you can alternatively use UrlParameter.Optional and you will get null for id

Your controller will look like:

```
public class ShoppingController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Shop(string id)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(id) || string.Equals(id, "DefaultProduct", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
        {
            // Do something to please the user
        }

        // Get product by id

        return View();
    }
}
```

And the routing code:

```
    public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Shopping",
            url: "shop/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Shopping", action = "Shop" , id = "DefaultProduct" }
        );

        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
    }
```